# Jersey, JSR 303 validation - custom "path" and "invalidValue" in ValidationError

Tags: java, validation, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I am using Jersey (JAX-RS) and I'm trying to implement a validation. I have a problem with a response returned by my application when a validation error occurs. Now the response looks like this:

```
[{
    "message": "Custom message",
    "messageTemplate": "{custom.message.template}",
    "path": "SomeJerseyResource.resourceMethod.arg0.names[0]",
    "invalidValue":"[value1, value2]"
}]
```

where "SomeJerseyResourceClass.resourceMethod" is a JAX-RS resource:

```
public class SomeJerseyResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    public Response resourceMethod(@Valid RequestModel request) {
        /** method body **/
    }
}
```

and validation constraint is assigned to a getter in RequestModel:

```
public class RequestModel {

    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    @MyConstraint
    public List<String> getNames() {
        return tags;
    }
}
```

I have a custom ConstraintValidator, where I validate each element of that List.

**Problem**

- I don't want to include resource and method name in "path" field of the response. Instead of 
  `SomeJerseyResource.resourceMethod.arg0.names[0]` I want `arg0.names[0]` only. Client doesn't know about server classes and methods, and he wouldn't be able to properly assign errors to fields when he receives response like that.
- I want to customize "invalidValue" field of a response. More specifically, to have only invalid element value, not the whole list in that field.

I didn't find any easy way to do that. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can just write an [`ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6525) to return the `Response` of your liking. Jersey uses an [`ExceptionMapper<ViolationException>`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13738). `ConstraintViolationException` extends from `ViolationException`, so you're mapper is more specific, and would take precedence in the choosing of the mapper. Jersey's mapper, returns the response as a [`ValidationError`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#bv.ValidationError), that's why the body is how it is. But you can make it whatever you want.

If you just want the `invalidValue` list, then just iterate through the `ConstraintViolation`s from `ContraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations()`, and get the `invalidValue` from the `ConstraintViolation`.